# How to call a function when a work item is finished in Boost.Asio?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, c++03

I would like to implement a command queue which handles incoming commands concurrently with a thread pool (so the queue grows temporarily when all threads are working). I would like to post a callback to the callers when a command worker is started and finished. My implementation is based on [this example](http://think-async.com/Asio/Recipes?skin=clean.nat,asio,pattern#A_thread_pool_for_executing_arbi) from the Asio website.

Is there a way to hook into these events and signal somehow? I would like to avoid the command functors knowing about the callbacks (since obviously I could call the callbacks inside the command functors).

Pseudocode to illustrate (initialization and error handling omitted for brevity):

```
class CommandQueue
{
public:
    void handle_command(CmdId id, int param)
    {
        io_service.post(boost::bind(&(dispatch_map[id]), param));

        // PSEUDOCODE:
        // when one of the worker threads start with this item, I want to call 
        callback_site.cmd_started(id, param);

        // when the command functor returns and the thread finished
        callback_site.cmd_finished(id, param);
    }

private:
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    asio::io_service::work work;
    std::map<CmdId, CommandHandler> dispatch_map; // CommandHandler is a functor taking an int parameter
    CallbackSite callback_site;
};
```

Is there a way to do this without having the command functors depend on the CallbackSite?

Comment: use case? Before I compile an answer, it seems to me like you want to dispatch a command that uses a bunch of threads and then block until it is done?

Comment: @IdeaHat There is an asynchronous source of commands. Some commands take more time than others. I want to implement a non-blocking queue that receives these commands, and a few threads will execute them asynchronously (1 command on 1 thread). There are currently 4 worker threads in the pool. If all worker threads are running, the command is added to the queue (which is what `post` does, to my understanding). I'm new to Asio, so my implementation might be completely wrong, too.

Comment: Personally, I'd define a function `void ProcessMap(CmdId id,int param) { callback_size.cmd_started(id,param); dispatch_map[id](param); callback_site.cmd_finished(id, param);}` and then post the cammands with `io_service.post(boost::bind(&CommandQueue::ProcessMap,this,id,param));`

Comment: @IdeaHat, mind posting that as an answer with a little explanation?

Comment: Huh. There's no other way to work with boost asio: io_service /calls back/ your completion handler at the end of the async operation. If you want to notify other parties, by all means, use Boost Signals2 or something (like you would otherwise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you want is to build in something that happens when one of the `run()` commands starts process a command, and then does something on return.

Personally, I do this by wrapping the function call:

```
    class CommandQueue
    {
    public:
        void handle_command(CmdId id, int param)
        {
            io_service.post(boost::bind(&CommandQueue::DispatchCommand, this,id,param));
        }

    private:
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        asio::io_service::work work;
        std::map<CmdId, CommandHandler> dispatch_map; // CommandHandler is a functor taking an int parameter
        CallbackSite callback_site;
        void DispatchCommand(CmdId id, int param)
        {
          // when one of the worker threads start with this item, I want to call 
          callback_site.cmd_started(id, param);
          dispatch_map[id](param);
          // when the command functor returns and the thread finished
          callback_site.cmd_finished(id, param);
        }
    };
```

This is also the pattern I use when I want to handle exceptions in the dispatched commands. You can also post different events instead of running them inline.

Answer (score 3):

My initial response would be that [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future)s are what you want given that [boost-asio](/questions/tagged/boost-asio) now even has [built in support for them](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/cpp2011/futures.html). However you have tagged this as [c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03) so you will have to make do with [boost::future](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures).

Basically you pass in a [boost::promise](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.promise) to the task you want to pass into `asio` but beforehand call `get_future` on it and store the `future` values which shares state with the `promise`. When the task finishes you can call `promise::set_value`. In another thread you can check to see if this has happened by calling `future::is_ready` (non-blocking) or `future::wait` (blocking) and then retrieve the value from it before calling the appropriate callback functions.

e.g. the value set could be a `CmdId` in your example to determine which callback to call.